# Center and evenly spread images with responsive stacking

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

Hello I have 3 images which are within a div.
I have managed to center the div however the images within it are still sticking to the left.
I would like to center and evenly space these images by around maybe 5 px.
When the width of the screen is narrow i.e phone size I would like these images to eventually stack vertically rather than adjust to become smaller but stay horizontal.

I have this so far (html):

```
        <section id="events" class="main style3 primary">
                <div><a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679"><img src="images/posters/minivalbigfoots.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" /></a></div>

                <div><a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679"><img src="images/posters/minivalbigfoots.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" /></a></div>

                <div><a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679"><img src="images/posters/minivalbigfoots.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" /></a></div>
        </section>
```

and this (css):

```
    #events {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .event-posters {
    max-width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float:left;
    }
```

Some of the styling is pre-written (i.e. main style3 primary) as I am customising a pre-existing template.

Let me know if you would require some more info on the prewritten css.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Remove the float, you can't center something using `margin:auto` if it's floated.

Comment: hi i removed the float however now they become stacked vertically. I added inline-block to maybe bring them back to horizontal but it didnt work.

Comment: If you make them `inline-block` then add `text-align-center` to the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to so something like this - [**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/8g3f32sf/1/embedded/result/)

```css
  #events {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  #events div {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<section id="events" class="main style3 primary">
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-150-2.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-150-2.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.residentadvisor.net/event.aspx?682679">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-250-150-2.jpg" class="event-posters" alt="ties spencer parker minival bigfoots tickets" />
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: they still remain vertically stacked in the center, a bit odd cause your example seems to work. Will make a few changes and see if I can get to the bottom of it.

Comment: They're stacked in the SO snippet because the window isn't wide enough to show them side by side.

Comment: I meant in the snippet they're fine, they're stacked on my version even though the screen is still fully wide.